# Apache Spark NumberformatException with content not existing in file

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, hdfs

Executing my spark app in local mode works perfectly fine but running on the cluster delivers an exception for a date field "yyyy-MM-dd hh:MM:ss" with following exception:

```
15/02/05 16:56:04 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, kmobd-dnode2.qudosoft.de): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ".1244E.1244E22"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at java.text.DigitList.getDouble(DigitList.java:169)
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.parse(DecimalFormat.java:2056)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subParse(SimpleDateFormat.java:2162)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1514)
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:364)
    at de.qudosoft.bd.econda.userjourneymapper.ClassifingMapper.call(ClassifingMapper.java:24)
    at de.qudosoft.bd.econda.userjourneymapper.ClassifingMapper.call(ClassifingMapper.java:10)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$pairFunToScalaFun$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:1002)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$pairFunToScalaFun$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:1002)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:389)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.spillToPartitionFiles(ExternalSorter.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:196)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What i dont understand is that the value ".1244E.1244E22" is not existing in my data. I am using Apache Spark 1.2.0 with Cloudera Manager CDH 5.3.0 and Hadoop 2.5.0.

This is my pom.xml:

```
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>de.qudosoft.bd.econda.userjourneymapper.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Did someone faced a similiar problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely that your parser is defined at a static/object instance level. The SimpleDateFormat class is not threadsafe, so state will get corrupted by competing threads.

Try moving your parser construction just before using it, at the function level. It's not as elegant or efficient, but it should prove the problem.

You could also trying mutexing the parse call and see if that helps. Profile/test it both ways and see which works better for you.

Best of luck!